# The princess' journey came to a crossroad

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual, anagram

This is a sequel to [A princess fell in love](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41655/a-princess-fell-in-love)

---

During her journey, the princess encountered a very strange crossroad.

Can you help you her choose a safe way to go to the prince? What would she encounter on each of the roads?

Here is a map of the road:

[image: top left][image: top middle][image: top right]
[image: bottom left][image: bottom right]

---

**Note:** **You can click on each road to view what the princess can see on each road.**

Comment: The cipher tag seems important, for all the answers have used anagrams....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel bad for stealing work so please do upvote the other answers.

(What exactly is the convention for "Who gets to compile all the answers"?)

What is at the end of each path:

**Direction** - Puzzle (Credit)

**Bottom Left** - "Free Silicon!" (Sconibulus)

> The sign says **Free Silicon!**, which is an anagram of **Fierce Lions!**.

**Bottom**

> This is going back the way we came. There is a very angry family at the end of this road. That is very bad.

**Bottom Right** - What even is this (Sconibulus)

> The words we have are: 
> **Bar Bar Ric Bites!** 
>  This is an anagram for: **Barbaric Tribes!**

**Top Right** - 4, 18, 16 (Radoslav Hristov)

> **4**, **18**, and **16** are the atomic numbers of the elements: **Beryllium**, **Argon**, and **Sulfur**. Their respective symbols are: **Be**, **Ar**, and **S**. When you put them together you get **Bears**.

**Top** - "Cross Point" (Sconibulus)

> The **t** is kinda blurred out so we just pretend it's not there. The words we are left with are: **Cross Poin**, which is an anagram for **Scorpions**.

**Top Left** - "Suffocation" (Me for once omg)

> The word **Suffocation** can be converted to **Butterflies** using a basic substitution cipher. 
>  Yeah I just kinda put "suffocation" in an online cryptogram solver and prayed. I'm not smart.

**Answer**

> The only path that leads to something probably friendly is the **top left** path leading to butterflies apparently. I guess we should choose the top left path.

(Please upvote the other partial answers though because I'm dumb.)

Comment: And what was the code used to get there? :O

Comment: The majestic code of brute force using online tools of course ^_^

Comment: And this is correct. Now only if we had a single answer combining all 5 and (although this should be obvious now) and which way should the princess take. :) PS. @greenturtle3141, I believe that turned out to be the hardest part to solve.

Comment: I would suggest you show the code for it.... That would make it easy to understand

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by "code"?

Comment: Hmmm, a single-word cryptogram. In my opinion, that's a bit too broad without a simple transformation rule like Caesar or Atbash. Perhaps the path leads to the coppermines? And it makes thw other signs ambiguous, too: "cross poin" could mean grass path or small gate when solved as cryptogram.

Comment: @M Oehm, using a simple substitution cipher on suffocation, got me two words only and they are related. PS. coppermines is not really a valid word - they are two separate words.

Comment: @MOehm, additionally, your two suggestions for "cross poin" are not descriptive enough - what would she encounter on the grass path, or after the small gate?

Comment: Okay, so copper mines is two words, but we don't know whether the cryptogram requires us to find spaces or not in the same way we don't know that it is a cryptogram at all. The anagrams are easy to see and are also signposted by the anagram tag. I stand by my criticism that I find the cryptogram solution a bit  disappointing.

Comment: As for the labels on the signs: If they were warning signs, they should spell out dangers, but if they are signposts, they should spell out destinations. The visual representation of the signs doesn't really tell which kind of sign they are. I like the basic premise of the puzzle, but I'm not so fond of the cryptotgram.

Comment: @MOehm, there is also a cipher tag. Besides, using cipher on the others could have turned out to too many combinations - so this should lead to the assumption they are not cryptograms. This one, on the other hand, when rearranged doesn't give much information, but when deciphered with a simple substitution cipher (since there are no clues for something more complicated), could lead to two words only - one ending with d and one with s. About spaces - I can easily include them in anagram and it would still be solvable. If I put them in a cipher as short as this one - it would be unsolvable.

Comment: Clearly, we have different views, so let's leave it at that. In general, I like your puzzles when I see them, but I'm often not convinced how they turn out.

Comment: Ok I compiled everything...

Comment: Good wrap-up of the partial answers with detailed explanations. I don't know whether there's an official way to combine partial answers into a final one, but your approach to reference the contributors is good. Don't feel bad about getting the tick mark; there's no bounty, so you get only a modest 15 rep. And don't be so harsh against yourself: You were smart enough to figure out the last missing item that no-one else could solve for two days or so. Using a tool for that is legit.

Answer (score 7):

Eep, not the bottom left, it has

> Fierce Lions

And the bottom right might have

> Barbaric Tribes

The top center has

> Scorpions

The top left warns of

> Suffocation, seems bad, or Taco I/O Snuff, which seems even worse, even if it does have guacamole.

Top top right one is more mysterious, but

> 4,18,16 comes out of an alphabet cipher as DRP... perhaps that means Don't Run, Princess... but Four Eighteen Sixteen can be anagrammed to "One hints, refugee exit."

So I pick

> The top right.

---

The top right has been pointed out to translate to

> Bears

And the top left appears to have a

> 'Fan of coitus' in addition to the suffocation and taco snuff... still staying away.

So I'm going to go

> Back the way I came, hopefully my family still loves me, or I can find a boat to Prince Laniff.

Comment: I would actually go to the top left because (ROT-13): `Gurer vf n tenl onpxtebhaq oruvaq gur yrggref P N naq G rkprcg vg vf n gvtre be fbzrguvat yby`. Not sure if you're deciphering of the top right is correct.

Comment: You got three of them right.

Comment: It's `4`, not `14`. So it's `DRP` (assuming the counting actually starts at 1). I think the princess just died, btw ;)

Comment: @LukasRotter probably, but anything to save her from the taco fate...

Comment: The last two are still wrong.

Comment: @Sconibulus But with `PNG`s I think the taco stuff would be bearable. (assuming I'm not color blind)

Comment: I have a feeling that top left might be right. It outright says something evil, but that's probably just a trick... right?!

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer, top right

> If we assume that these are the numbers of elements from periodic table we get 4=Be, 18=Ar, 16=S, i.e. Bears. I wouldn't go there if I were the princess.

To avoid confusion I removed a guess which was wrong.

Comment: @MariaDeleva All of them look like bad places. Is it a matter of choosing the least evil?

Comment: You will know which one to choose when you have all 5. :)

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I'll just post my guess as a community answer.

> Sconibulus and Radoslav Hristov figured out everything except the top left. Which, in my opinion, is the safe one. Because if you notice there is a gray background behind the substring `CAT` in SUFFO**CAT**ION.
> This seems like the best option, let's just hope it's a domestic cat.

Comment: Still wrong. Perhaps it is something you overlooked?

Comment: Overlooked? So does the visual tag apply to the remaining path? Because in the other pictures the graphics were just adornment as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

Top left:

> Suffocation can be anagramed as Cautions Off.

Top center (as @Sconibulus said):

> Scorpions

Top right(as @Radoslav Hristov said):

> Bears

Bottom Left (as @Sconibulus said):

> Fierce Lions

Bottom Right (as @Sconibulus said):

> Barbaric Tribes

So:

> The princess should pick Top left since as other roads leads to dangers.

Comment: I will disappoint you but I gave the same answer and it turned out that it was wrong.

Comment: Then my answer is completely useless xD