# The princess arrived safely at the castle

Tags: story, password, steganography

The princess took the correct and safest path on the [crossroad](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41929/the-princess-journey-came-to-a-crossroad), seeing lots of beautiful butterflies along the way and is now standing in front of prince Laniff's castle. However, it turns out she needs a password to enter.

The princess tried hard to remember whether the prince has given her any hints towards the password, but no luck.

So she decided to stand patiently outside and ask whoever goes out of the castle for the password.

The first person she asked, said to her: "I will not give you the password, but please, tell me what do you think of this poem?"

> Lightning appeared in the storm
>   And my path was shown.
>   Seeing this was the norm,
>   Thunder struck upon.
>
> Although it was night,
>   Nothing hinders my way.
>   Day is coming bright,
>   Further I cannot say.
>
> Is the night still here?
>   Ray of light appears,
>   Stripping away my fears.
>   The goal now is near.

The poem wasn't really very good, but the princess wanted to be polite, so she said she liked it very much.

She started waiting for the next person, but he didn't want to give her the password either. Instead, he gave her a piece of paper with some numbers scribbled on it and said: "I am pretty sure these numbers will win the lottery next time!" The numbers appeared a bit strange, so the princess thought the man was just confused:

> 2 8 | 2 4 | 6 | 7 14 | 2 5 | 5 | 0

Next, the princess asked a woman about the password. The woman said: "I can't straightforward give you the password as it is against our rules, however I have hidden it in this message. You look like a smart one, you will be able to figure it out, I am sure." Then she handed the princess a piece of paper:

> Please note that you are not in Morocco  - we have no dahirs here.
>   Our mate is individualism and we va**l**ue our people greatly. 
>   We are loc**a**ted in a plateau, but we are not defenseless. 
>   We sing songs in our king's name - for him we will walk in lava.
>   Our castle keeps i**t**s secrets.
>   Being smart is the important th**i**ng here.
>   Read carefully a**n**d they will be revealed.

What is the password?

Comment: How long is the password?

Comment: @LukasRotter, isn't it too early for hints? :) Let's just say it is not 5 letters. :)

Comment: Just wanted to see if the obvious 3-digit answer is right :P (pretty sure it isn't)

Comment: `714` or `7|14`? In fact there are extra spaces elswhere in the lottery numbers...

Comment: In case you wondered, my guess would've been `ACI`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Nemo me impune lacessit / No one can harm me unpunished

The poem tells us to:

> Take the first and last (first letters of each line)

The lottery numbers tell us to:

> Take the 2nd and 8th word from the first sentence of the message, 2nd and 4th from the second sentence etc.

The message then gives us:

> *Latin*, in bold letters. When we take the first and last letters of the words we got from the lottery numbers, we get the sentence "Nemo me impune lacessit", which is latin for "No one can harm me unpunished".

Answer (score 3):

Probably wrong but here we go:

> The password is  KLNX
>  From the poem's first letter we get FIRST AND LAST
>  From the lottery numbers we get (by adding in pairs and then removing first and last and treating them as separate numbers)
>  2 8 0
>  2 4 5
>  6 2 5
>  7 14
>  which gives us numbers 10, 11, 13, 21.
>  From the bold letters in the secret message we get the word 'latin' and using the above numbers as index in the Latin alphabet we get the letters K L N X

Comment: This is not the correct answer. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva that's my best answer.

Comment: Let's just say this is not how you use the numbers.